# Quartz scheduler locks database when it fails to connect

Tags: java, database, quartz-scheduler

I'm using Quartz 2.2.2 in clustering mode and Spring 4.2.
I'm facing an issue with Quartz because he locks the DB when it is not able to connect to the DB.
When I say the DB is locked, I mean the DB will locked the profile which is trying to connect with the wrong password for instance. Quartz will try to connect while he's failing, and the DB will lock the profile for safety. 
I would like to know if it is possible to limit the connection attempts of Quartz when it fails ?

Quartz.properties :

```
#============================================================================
# Configure Main Scheduler Properties  
#============================================================================

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = MyScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO

#============================================================================
# Configure ThreadPool  
#============================================================================

org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 1

#============================================================================
# Configure JobStore  
#============================================================================

org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = false
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = quartzDS
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 20000

#============================================================================
# Configure Datasources  
#============================================================================

org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDS.jndiURL=java:/comp/env/jdbc/E760
```

Do you have any idea ? I took a look to the quartz's doc' but I did not find something to help me.
There is a similar post to this one there :
[Quartz Scheduler locks the database user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25667774/quartz-scheduler-locks-the-database-user)

But I would like to know if there is/are another way to solve it.

Thanks a lot.